# Imagem com opção de zoom ou map view baseado na imagem

Tags: ios, swift

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação onde preciso inserir um mapa de um local interno (logo o map view da apple não tem registrado ) , gostaria de saber se tem como montar um mapView (montando o local interno ) ou caso não tenha se posso inserir uma ImgView e permitir que de zoom , pois tenhoi a planta em jpg ?
Obrigado

Código atual :

```
class MapasViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var imgMapa: UIImageView! // *** Declara imgView
@IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
func viewForZoomingInScrollView(scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
    return imgMapa
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    print("*** LOG : TELA DE MAPAS CARREGADA ***")


    let width: CGFloat = imgMapa.image!.size.width
    let height: CGFloat = imgMapa.image!.size.height

    scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1.0
    scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 6.0
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(width, height)
    scrollView.delegate = self
    scrollView.zoomScale = 1.0

}




}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Minha resposta vai para a segunda opção, pois não sei se com o `MKMapKit` você consegue fazer isso.

O que você precisa, basicamente, é colocar um `UIImageView` em um `UIScrollView`. Se estiver utilizando o *interface builder* e *auto layout*, adicione os seguintes elementos:

```
UIScrollView
|_ UIView
   |_ UIImageView
```

E com eles, suas respectivas *constraints* para obedecer qualquer tamanho de tela.

E no `UIViewController`, o *delegate* e as propriedades ligadas:

```
class MapaViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var imgMapa: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
}
```

O que irá definir esta imagem como habilitada para dar zoom é o *delegate* do `UIScrollView`:

```
func viewForZoomingInScrollView(scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
    return imgMapa
}
```

E por fim, ao carregar a tela, defina as propriedades do `UIScrollView`:

```
let width: CGFloat = imgMapa.image!.size.width
let height: CGFloat = imgMapa.image!.size.height

scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1.0
scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 6.0
scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(width, height)
scrollView.delegate = self
scrollView.zoomScale = 1.0
```

Com isso, você será capaz de executar os gestos para dar zoom na imagem.

Comment: Amigo realizei o que você falou... Se não definir a imagem ele encerra o app, se defino a imagem não aparece, fica branco, coloquei as definições que vc falou no didload, esta certo? sabe como posso resolver ?

Comment: adicionei o código para melhor entendimento

Comment: Experimente colocar no `viewDidAppear`. A imagem precisa ser definida, caso contrário, no momento que você for obter `imgMapa.image`, vai voltar nulo.

Comment: Amigo resolveu, tinha esquecido de colocar a view dentro do UIVIew, obrigadooooo